# Jquery UI datePicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this code

```
$("#calendar").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $('.selected-date').html(dateText);
        }

    });
```

I am looking for a way to send the date in 1 format to the database with ajax(not shown) and also update a div with a different date format. 
What is the best way to do this?

**Update # 1**

```
$("#calendar").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

  var fmt2 = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm-dd-yy", dateText);
  $(".selected-date").html(fmt2);
    }

    });
```

**Update # 2**

```
$("#calendar").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var d = new Date(dateText);
    var fmt2 = $.datepicker.formatDate("DD, d MM, yy", d);
    $(".selected-date").html(fmt2);



}

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already got the function that's called when a date is selected, so you can then do something similar to the following:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
  $('.selected-date').html(dateText);

  var fmt1 = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", dateText);
  $.get("/your/ajax/url/" + fmt1, yourCallbackFunction);

  var fmt2 = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm-dd-yy", dateText);
  $("#someotherdiv").html(fmt2);
}
```

Not tested but should work... :-)

**Update #1**

Looks like the datepicker.formatDate() function needs a Date object to work with.  The following works here...

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
  $('.selected-date').html(dateText);

  var d = new Date(dateText);

  var fmt1 = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/y", d);
  $.get("/your/ajax/url/" + fmt1, yourCallbackFunction);

  var fmt2 = $.datepicker.formatDate("MM o, yy", d);
  $("#someotherdiv").html(fmt2);
}
```

Comment: Just had chance to test - you're right :-) let me have a quick look and I'll get back to you :-)

Comment: I could use the altfield/altformat if there was a way to go into a div and not input.

Comment: Very bizarre. Not that it should matter, but what versions of jQuery, jQueryUI have you got? 1.3.2, 1.7.2 here.  Can you try http://www.richsage.co.uk/bits/jqueryui/ui.html and see if the result is the same?

Comment: Odd I copied the code you have on the source and it works fine. No clue what the difference is.